# Memory map region per thread,

Tags: java

Does Memory map region per thread work?  The main thread creates the RandomAccessFile and Channel. The worker threads use the channel to map non- overlapping region for individual use. One disk file but multiple regions for each thread.

Comment: I don't think so.  You can have more than one memory-mapped file, but memory mapping doesn't work on a per-thread basis.  It's always global, like heap memory.  Also I understand that Java cannot *free* memory mapped spaces, so eventually you could run out of space available for memory mapping.  Caveat emptor.

Comment: Why wouldn't work?  The channel is thread safe.  Mapping a region will give you a ByteBuffer.  You can have multiple ByteBuffers  for non-overlapping regions. Each worker will  work only with a single ByteBuffer. I don't see why this is a problem?